# To prevent automatic type change in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a excel (.xslx) file with 4 columns:
pmid (int)
gene (string)
disease (string)
label (string)

I attempt to load this directly into python with `pandas.read_excel`

```py
df = pd.read_excel(path, parse_dates=False)
```

capture from excel

[image: excel snippet]

capture from pandas using my ide debugger

[image: pandas]

As shown above, **pandas** tries to be smart, automatically converting some of **gene** fields such as ***3.Oct***, ***4.Oct*** to a datetime type. The issue is that ***3.Oct*** or ***4.Oct*** is a abbreviation of Gene type and totally different meaning. so I don't want pandas to do so. How can I prevent pandas from converting types automatically?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

In fact, there is no conversion. The value appears as `2020-10-03 00:00:00` in Pandas because it is the real value stored in the cell. Excel show this value in another format

[image: excel date]

---

**Update 2**:

To keep the same format as Excel, you can use `pd.to_datetime` and a custom function to reformat the date.

```
# Sample
>>> df
                  gene
0               PDGFRA
1  2021-10-03 00:00:00  # Want: 3.Oct
2  2021-10-04 00:00:00  # Want: 4.Oct

>>> df['gene'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['gene'], errors='coerce')
                    .apply(lambda dt: f"{dt.day}.{calendar.month_abbr[dt.month]}"
                                      if dt is not pd.NaT else np.NaN)
                    .fillna(df['gene']))

>>> df
     gene
0  PDGFRA
1   3.Oct
2   4.Oct
```

---

**Old answer**

Force `dtype=str` to prevent Pandas try to transform your dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, dtype=str)
```

Or use `converters={'colX': str, ...}` to map the dtype for each columns.

Comment: str type does not work. still pandas automatically changes 3.oct to timeframe

Comment: Is there a way to read the "real value" instead of "shown value"? I read the value and met the look up error, i need to search DB with the text '3.Oct' but the input query is changed to raise error in the program.

Comment: The real value is the value displayed by Pandas. This is what you already have IIUC. Do you want to get "3. Oct" instead?

Comment: @KeanuPaik. I updated my answer. Can you check if it's what you expect, please?

Comment: @@Corralien Thank you for your support. However, gene column in real data length is over 100,000, but only one row is a problem. To handle this, it is a bit unfamiliar for me to check whether all columns are calendar or not in advance. As you mentioned before, if the intrinsic value in the cell has not changed, only the outer format has changed, is there any way to read the raw intrinsic value?

Answer (score -1):

[`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) has a `dtype` argument you can use to specify data types explicitly.

Comment: no it doesn't work